# Div on top of each other

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 divs of video and image and I want to selectively show/display using JQuery
but not actually hide it with `.hide` or `.show()`, please ignore the shopify code.

When a user clicks on the thumbnails below, how do I stack them on top of each other using JQuery/CSS but not using the `.hide` or `.show` method?

```
<div id="mainVideoContainer">
    <video id="mainVideo" width="320" height="240" autoplay controls>
        <source src="http:video.mp4" type="video/mp4">      
    </video>
</div>
<div class="mainImageContainer">
    <a href=""><img src="imageurl"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to clarify your question with some screenshots ... why not use hide / show?

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS you can position both divs on top of each other.

First, wrap the divs with a wrapper to serve as a point of reference:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div id="mainVideoContainer" class="layer">
   <video id="mainVideo"   width="320" height="240" autoplay controls>
      <source src="http:video.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
   </video>
  </div>
   <div class="mainImageContainer layer">
    <a href=""><img src="imageurl"/></a>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Then, position both divs on top of each other:

```
.wrapper {
position:relative; // point of reference
}

.layer {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

As for determining which is visible, you can use either the `z-index` or the `display` property

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLLDf/) out. change the `z-index` value and see how the one with higher value is the one showing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css z-index property. The item with the highest index will be at the top level of the stack.
I your can you can use jQuery to change the z-index when the user clicks the button.

```
 <html>
    <head><title>Z-Index</title>
     <style>
    img
   {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:-1;
 }
 </style>
 </head>

  <body>
 <h1>This is a heading</h1>
 <img src="w3css.gif" width="100" height="140" />
 <p>Because the image has a z-index of -1, it will be placed behind the text.</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

You might find this tutorial useful in getting familiar with z-indez css property http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something like this, which will switch z-index on click:

```
$('.tab').click(function(e){
    $('.tab').css('z-index', 1)
    $(this).css('z-index', 10);    
});
```

And don't forget to set in css `.tab {position: relative}`,
For more details check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dP4NX/1/